# How to revert last APK on Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play, apk

I have uploaded an APK to the Google Play store. However, after making it live, I have found an issue in the APK. My current APK version is 1.5 and I want to cancel this APK and reinstate the previous version (1.4) in the store. Is this possible?

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no rollback feature.

The only way is to take your good APK (1.4), increase its versionCode (e.g. to 1.6), then re-sign it and re-publish it in a new release.